# Read message from text file and display in message box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, newline, streamreader

JavaError.128 = "project creation failed. & vbLf & Please try again and if the problem persists then contact the administrator"

I am able to read this message from text file. the issue is vbLf is not considered as newline in msgbox. it prints vbLf in msgbox.

```
Using sr As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(errorfilePath)
 While ((sr.Peek() <> -1))
  line = sr.ReadLine
  If line.Trim().StartsWith("JavaError." & output) Then
    isValueFound = True
    Exit While
  End If
 End While
sr.Close()
End Using

If isValueFound Then
Dim strArray As String() = line.Split("="c)
MsgBox(strArray(1).Replace("""", "").Trim({" "c}))
End If
```

Comment: It looks like you have the vbLf as part of the string in the txt file, thats right?

Comment: yes.
I need new line at that position in msgbox.

Comment: So I think you will have to identify the vbLf within your text string and replace it with the function as such. Try to create an array using the "&" as separator: txtFile.Split("&")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all your code a simpler one line version using File.ReadAllLines and LINQ. This code will put all the lines starting with javaerror into the textbox, not just the first:

```
textBox.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(errorFilePath) _
    .Where(Function(s) s.Trim().StartsWith("JavaError")) _
    .Select(Function(t) t.Substring(t.IndexOf("= ") + 2).Replace(" & vbLf & ", Environment.NewLine)) _
    .ToArray()
```

You need to Imports System.IO and System.Linq

This code reads all the lines of the file into an array, then uses LINQ to pull out only those starting with java error, then projects a new string of everything after the `=` with vbLf replaced with a newline, converts the enumerable projection to an array of strings and assigns it to the textBox lines

If you don't want all the lines but instead only the first:

```
textBox.Text = File.ReadLines(errorFilePath) _
    .FirstOrDefault(Function(s) s.Trim().StartsWith("JavaError")) _
    ?.Substring(t.IndexOf("= ") + 2).Replace(" & vbLf & ", Environment.NewLine))
```

This one uses ReadLine instead of ReadALlLines - ReadLines works progressively, and it makes sense to be able to stop reading after we foundt he first rather than have the overhead of reading ALL (million) lines only to then end up pulling the first out and throwing 999,999 lines of effort away. So it's reading line by line, pulls out the first that starts with "JavaError" (or Nothing if there is no such line), then checks if Nothing came out (the `?`) and skips the Substring if it was Nothing, or it does a Substring on everything after the `=` and replaces vbLf with newline

For a straight up mod of your original code:

```
Using sr As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(errorfilePath)
 While ((sr.Peek() <> -1))
  line = sr.ReadLine
  If line.Trim().StartsWith("JavaError." & output) Then
    isValueFound = True
    line = line.Replace(" & vbLf & ", Environment.NewLine))
    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ added code
    Exit While
  End If
 End While
sr.Close()
End Using

If isValueFound Then
Dim strArray As String() = line.Split("="c)
MsgBox(strArray(1).Replace("""", "").Trim({" "c}))
End If
```

Note that I've always made my replacement on `& vbLf &` with a space at each end to avoid stray spaces being left behind - if your file sometimes doesn't have them, consider using Regex to do the replace, e.g. `Regex.Replace(line, " ?& vbLf & ?", Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
 Dim txtFile As String = "project creation failed. & vbLf & Please try again and if the problem persists then contact the administrator"
        Dim arraytext() As String = txtFile.Split("&")
        Dim txtMsgBox As String = Nothing
        For Each row As String In arraytext
            If Trim(row) = "vbLf" Then
                txtMsgBox = txtMsgBox & vbLf
            Else
                txtMsgBox = txtMsgBox & Trim(row)
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox(txtMsgBox)
```